# Which exceptions to catch in a FaultHandler activity in Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, state-machine

Im learning Windows Workflow at the minute and am now looking at exception handling in state machines. 
Basically I can see that a FaultHandler can be used to catch a specific exception thrown in an activity. 
My question is do I need to specifically catch each type of exception or is there a way I can catch all exceptions with one FaultHandler?
Im sure this isn't best practice(any suggestions there?), but just interested to understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly catch the exceptions you think might occur.

You could have a general purpose exception that handled the base `Exception` class, but that would potentially hide problems with your code. You would need to log all exceptions and have some way of both letting the user know that there had been a problem and getting this information back to you so that you can correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all if you set the FaultType to System.Exception.